# Как правильно писать: информационно-туристический или информационно-туристский портал

Tags: употребление-слов

Здравствуйте, мнения разделились по поводу правильного написания названия: информационно-туристический портал или информационно-туристский портал? И еще вопрос по поводу слова: Бронь (в значении совершить бронирование номера), правильно ли написание Номер брони, Бронь, Бронирование - есть ли какие-нибудь ограничения на использование слова бронь?

Answer (score 1):

А. Думаю, что вариант информационно-туристический является более предпочтительным.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Во многих толковых словарях указывается, что прилагательные туристский и туристический относятся  и  к туризму, и к туристам, то есть могут заменять друг друга. В то же время слово туристический является более универсальным по области применения, в то время как "туристский" обычно относят к материальным объектам (палатка, снаряжение и др.).

Также следует учесть, что в слове "информационно-туристический" сочетаются близкие по стилю слова, в отличие от варианта "информационно-туристский".

Б. В орфоэпическом словаре Резниченко приводится слово "брОня" в значении "закрепление лица или предмета", это существительное 1-ого склонения акцентного класса А, то есть имеет неизменяемое ударение на основе во всех формах: брОня - брОни - брОню.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Хотелось бы иметь статистику по  употреблению слов бронь/брОня. Если мы наберем в Грамоте.ру слово "бронь", то увидим, что оно там присутствует. Также можно набрать слово "брОня" и увидеть, что  оно там тоже  есть. (Кто у нас  ответственный за словари на Грамоте.ру?).

А вообще говоря, история этих слов интересна. В др.-рус. языке слово бронЯ со значением "панцирь, кольчуга"  используется с 11 века: о.-с. корень born, заимствование из языков германской группы, также "боронити" -  защищать, оберегать.

БрОня с переосмысленным значением  - слово новое, послереволюционное (впервые отмечено в словаре Ушакова в 1935 году). Возможно, что весь последующий период народное сознание пыталось переосмыслить и фонетику этого слова, чему упорно препятствовала официальная лингвистика. Так,  орфоэпический словарь Аванесова (1983 год) строго предупреждает: бронь - неправильно!

Казалось бы, почему бы не изменить норму, если она широко используется в языке? Ведь БрОня - это еще и имя Бронислав, а слова с разным значением брОнь/бронЯ  различались бы и по произношению, и по написанию. Но нет! Пусть будет брОня, а также лишний повод разделить общество на грамотных и неграмотных.

Comment: Я представляю, если турист в ваучере увидит Броня №21 к примеру, вот смеху то будет!

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, слово "туристический" связано с понятием "туризм", а пароним "туристский" - с "туристами". Это портал для туристов, значит, информационно-туристский.

Comment: На мой взгляд портал все же о туризме, а не о туристах. Мы же пишем статьи об отдыхе и развлечениях, а не о конкретных туристах. Исходя из этих умозаключений и опираясь на ваш ответ, мне кажется, что правильно писать информационно-туристический. Я не прав?

Comment: Я ведь написал "портал ДЛЯ туристов", а не "о туристах", поэтому, исходя из его предназначения, думаю, все же  вернее было бы употребить "туристский". Впрочем, грань здесь настолько тонка, что можно склониться и в одну, и в другую сторону, ведь туристы занимаются туризмом.

Comment: меня сегодня по этому вопросу опустил местный министр по туризму, типа какой я безграмотный, если грань тонка, какой вариант предпочтительней, туристский? еще он говорил, что-то о том, что слова бронь нет, а есть броню, и обосновал это тем, что женский род, тут у меня вообще взрыв мозга произошел.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, слову «портал» более созвучно слово «туристический». По правде сказать, я бы и палатку туристской не назвал. А что до того, что «турист – туристский, туризм – туристический»,  так не говорим же «поэт – поэтский». И поэт, и поэзия – поэтические. Или: политик – политский,  И политик, и политика – политические.  Не пишите «бронь» - не звучит, «брОня» (с ударением на первый слог) – тоже не звучит. Представьте себе директора, просящего забронировать что-нибудь: « Эллочка, закажите мне брОню на завтра, пожалуйста!» - так она ему, извиняюсь, проститутку вызовет. Пусть я и прослыву человеком неграмотным, но от слова «броня» с ударением на второй слог не откажусь.

Comment: А  почему  бы  не  сказать: забронируйте  место,  билет,  номер  в  гостинице ?  Бронируют  всегда  что-то  определённое.

Comment: Тогда вопрос с бронёй отпадает сам собой.

Answer (score 0):

А вот и ответ Грамоты.ру: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_193 ; И  мнение Института русского языка Академии наук СССР.http://www.frontdesk.ru/vetka.cgi?vetkaid=4664

Answer (score 0):

1. информационно-туристический портал или 2. информационно-туристский портал?
2. относится к туризму: экипировка, приборы, аптечки, спальники...
3. ... к туристу: маршрут, цена, условия...

Я бы начал с 2. А после входа в портал дать дополн. инфо.

Comment: И еще вопрос по поводу слова: Бронь (в значении совершить бронирование номера).
Бронь - право на пользование, у него не может быть номера. Номер может быть на документе о таком праве, его - этот документ - и надо назвать. Разрешение № 23 на получение...